# CodeIgniter Zip Class: Allowed memory exhausted

Tags: php, codeigniter, memory, zip

I am working in CodeIgniter. What I am trying to do is download the zip file created by the ZIP class of CodeIgniter, and i am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 30381518 bytes) in ..\system\core\Output.php on line 366
```

My PHP code:

```
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        if ($attachment->type === 'file') {
            $data = @file_get_contents($uploadDirectory . $attachment->fullPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $attachment->physicalName);
            $attachment->location = ltrim($attachment->location, '/');
            $fileName = $attachment->location ? $attachment->location . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $attachment->name : $attachment->name;
            $this->zip->add_data($fileName, $data);
        }
    }
```

Please can anyone help me to resolve this error, and Thanks for any help!

Comment: this is not error, this is code! what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Increase allowed memory for PHP in php.ini?

Comment: The amount of memory required by your code exceeds the available amount of memory that you have been allocated in your environment. Just as @D.Kasipovic has stated, you need to increase your memory limit, or refine your query and loops so it doesn't require so much memory.

Comment: What is the effects / disadvantages if the memory_limit variable in php.ini changed to -1.

Answer (score 1):

changing the memory_limit by

`ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` overrides the default [PHP memory limit.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)

or if worried using so try,

After enable these two lines.
It's started working

```
; Determines the size of the realpath cache to be used by PHP. This value should
; be increased on systems where PHP opens many files to reflect the quantity of
; the file operations performed.
; http://php.net/realpath-cache-size
realpath_cache_size = 16k

; Duration of time, in seconds for which to cache realpath information for a given
; file or directory. For systems with rarely changing files, consider increasing this
; value.
; http://php.net/realpath-cache-ttl
realpath_cache_ttl = 120
```

[image]

Comment: What is the effects / disadvantages if the memory_limit variable in php.ini changed to -1

Comment: you are telling the server to just use all the memory that it wants.

Comment: this is correct? Please can anyone help me to resolve this error!

Comment: When i change the value to "-1" i get this error: 
The connection was reset

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.